# How to disable rainbow-delimiters for Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

I've added `dotspacemacs-excluded-packages '(rainbow-delimiters)` at my **.spacemacs** file. (This is the only instance of the rainbow-delimiters at the whole file.) I've restarted Spacemacs and nothing happened. I still have the delimiters in a different color, which depends on my cursor position.

[image]

Comment: you can disable `rainbow-delimiters-mode` with `SPC t C d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable `rainbow-delimiters-mode` with

```
SPC t C d
```